# Does GLKit work in Swift playgrounds?

Tags: swift, opengl-es, swift-playground

I've seen a couple of articles showing GLKView's in Swift playgrounds, but I can't get it to work. All I see is a light gray view. I would expect it to be blue.

I'm using Xcode 6.4

```
import UIKit
import GLKit
import XCPlayground

class RGView: GLKView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        glClear(GLbitfield(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT))
    }
}

let view = RGView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200), context: EAGLContext(API: .OpenGLES2))
view.setNeedsDisplay()

// tried with and without this
XCPShowView("RGView", view)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL views, using GLKit or otherwise, do not currently work in playgrounds. If you’d like them to, you should [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Answer (score 0):

This code works in an Xcode 9.2 Playground:

```
import GLKit
import PlaygroundSupport

// Subclass of GLKViewController.
final class ViewController: GLKViewController {
  private var _glkView: GLKView!
  private var _context: EAGLContext?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupGLContext()
    setupGLView()
  }

  override func glkView(_ view: GLKView, drawIn rect: CGRect) {
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0)
    glClear(GLbitfield(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT))
  }

}


extension ViewController {

  func setupGLContext() {
    _context = EAGLContext(api: .openGLES2)
    if _context == nil {
      print("Failed to create ES context.")
    }

    EAGLContext.setCurrent(_context)
  }

  func setupGLView() {
    _glkView = self.view as! GLKView
    _glkView.context = _context!
    _glkView.drawableDepthFormat = .format24
    _glkView.isOpaque = true
    _glkView.delegate = self
    _glkView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 350, height: 500)
  }

}


// Create instance of ViewController and tell playground to show it in live view
let vc = ViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc.view
```